# Change UICollectionViewCell height after loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I'm loading a collectionView.
When I press on a button I need to change the cell height.
The only way that I found is to call "reloadData", But this is not good for me because I don't want to reload the cell.
Is there a way to change the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalidating the `UICollectionViewLayout` will force a layout pass.

```
[collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
```

If you want to change a small number of cells rather than invalidating the entire layout, you can use `invalidateLayoutWithContext:` for more targeted updates.

Answer (score 0):

On the sender action of your button get cell instance and update height width constraint as per use.  hope this will work.